# How do you express "my fascination in xx didn't grow instantly but was built up" more elegantly?

Tags: expressions

I want to express the statement, "my fascination in xx didn't grow instantly, but was built up". How do I make it more elegantly, and more natively?

Edit: I am writing my statement of purpose for graduate studies. "xx" is a subject, the program to which I'm applying.

Comment: Using "grow" usually means it increased over time.

Comment: @Peter I want to express that my fascination was not "explosive", it was not "love at first sight", but it grew as time went by. I don't know how to express the "explosive" part.

Comment: We usually say "my fascination _with_ xx" not "_in_ xx".

Comment: OP, kindly state whether XX is a person, object, concept or other things. Also provide a detailed scenario, context and more explanation as it  will help members  in providing   better answers.

Comment: @banuyayi Sorry about the ambiguity. I am writing my statement of purpose for graduate studies. "xx" is a subject, the program to which I'm applying.

Answer (score 1):

You have already said it, just say what you mean:

> My fascination with _____ grew over time.

Here are some variations:

> I wasn't particularly excited about ___ at first, but the more I was exposed to it, the more fascinated I became.

> I went from mildly interested to completely fascinated in about two weeks!

Answer (score 0):

Sober sentences

```
My fascination with xx grew over time. (already mentioned by swmcdonnell)
My fascination in xx built up gradually.
My fascination in xx "built up steadily"/"steadily grew".
```

Flamboyant sentences (can also be used to show interest in someone)(xx can be replaced with the name of person of interest if that is the intent)

```
Earlier I was only fascinated with xx, now I am in thrall.
The more I became fascinated with xx, the more I became its(her) captive.
It took little time from fascination in/with xx to enthrallment.
Imperceptibly my fascination in/with xx grew.
Impalpably My fascination in/with xx grew.
My fascination in/with xx built up in fits and starts. 
Languorously my fascination in/with xx grew.
```

Note: "fascination with", "fascination for", "fascination of", "fascination in" can all be used depending on the context.

[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fascination) example sentences: "There is a certain peculiar fascination in the stories."

Comment: Many of these don't convey what the OP is trying to say at all. 'Impalpably' seems completely unnatural. And it's good practice to explain *why* your options might fit the context.

Comment: OP had two basic requirements, 1. Grew, 2. Not instantly. My answers/sentence options fulfill these two requirements. I tried to cover the manner/s in which it (fascination growing, but not instantly) may happen. I tried to stay clear of the "auxiliary" requirement of "elegant" as it is too subjective. And it is not required to use the sentences as such. Modifications may be made to suit the OP's purposes.

Comment: Many of these examples are too flamboyant for a statement of purpose. The language should be engaging, yes, but sober.

Comment: I agree with you. The sentences needed  to be categorised into sober and flamboyant. Sober sentences can be/could be used everywhere, while one has to be circumspect when using the flamboyant ones

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of meaning, one slightly awkward aspect of "*my fascination in xx didn't grow instantly, but was built up*" is that the two halves don't quite match.

"didn't grow" and "was built" aren't from the same point of view.

It would be more natural to say "wasn't grown" and "was built".